# Match everything before last section of url

Tags: php, regex

I want to match everything in a URL up to the last section.

So I want to match: `http://www.test.com/one/two/` in all of the following cases:

```
http://www.test.com/one/two/three
http://www.test.com/one/two/three/
http://www.test.com/one/two/three/?foo=bar
```

I'm working in PHP and currently I have `/.+\/(?=[^\/]+\/?$)/` this matches everything except the last case but I can't seem to 'not match a forward slash unless it's followed by a question mark' which would seeming sort the problem?

Comment: Why don't you just use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse_url)?

Comment: `parse_url` doesn't split the path name into dirs, which seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: I could use parse_url and take off the last section with a much simpler regex afterwards but I thought I'd try and do it just with one regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, richieahb

**The regex:**

```
(?m)http://[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*/(?!\?)(?=[^/\n]+)
```

**The test (with one more level added)**

```
<?php
$string = "http://www.test.com/one/two/three
http://www.test.com/one/two/three/
http://www.test.com/one/two/three/four
http://www.test.com/one/two/three/four/
http://www.test.com/one/two/three/?foo=barv";

$regex="~(?m)http://[^/]+(?:/[^/]+)*/(?!\?)(?=[^/\r\n]+)~";

preg_match_all($regex,$string,$m);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($m[0]);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**The Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.test.com/one/two/
    [1] => http://www.test.com/one/two/
    [2] => http://www.test.com/one/two/three/
    [3] => http://www.test.com/one/two/three/
    [4] => http://www.test.com/one/two/
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'http://www.test.com/one/two/three http://www.test.com/one/two/three/ http://www.test.com/one/two/three/?foo=bar';
preg_match_all('#http://(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/#is', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: That fails for anything with another level in the url hierarchy.  This should be for all possible urls.